# Biblatex Incollection: Comma after Booktitle

Tags: biblatex

The period after the booktitle should be a comma. While I found similar problems and their solutions, I wasn't able to solve mine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{foo,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Title},
    booktitle = {Booktitle},
    editor = {Editor},
    location = {Location},
    year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{foo}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about other punctuation? Should that stay as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package to patch the bibdrivers to include a comma instead of the default `\newunitpunct` (inserted by `\newunit`) after the `title` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{foo,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Title},
    booktitle = {Booktitle},
    editor = {Editor},
    location = {Location},
    year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\def\dopatchbibdrivereditorcomma#1{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \newunit\newblock}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock}
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to patch driver for type #1}}}
\forcsvlist{\dopatchbibdrivereditorcomma}{inbook,incollection,inproceedings}

\begin{document}
\nocite{foo}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]